# Errorless problems with discord.ext.tasks

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my first time using this and whenever I r un the code below, it prints "waiting..." but nothing else. As I said I haven't really used discord.ext.tasks before so I'm not 100% sure on how everything works.

`christmas.py` in Cogs folder

```py
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.index = 0
        self.bot = bot
        self.printer.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.printer.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
    async def printer(self):
        print(self.index)
        self.index += 1

    @printer.before_loop
    async def before_printer(self):
        print('waiting...')
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

I got this code straight from the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html) so I'm kinda confused.

I was asked to send my main.py here so:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from variables import cogs, success, failed, status, MY_GUILD, TOKEN 
import logging
import json
from Cogs.tickets import panelSelectView
from ticket_functions import *

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(">"), intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    synced = await bot.tree.sync()
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})")
    print(f"Loaded {success}") if failed == [] else print(f"Loaded {success}\nFailed to load {failed}")
    print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands.")  
    await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name=status))

@bot.tree.command(name="sync", description="Syncs all of the slash commands.")
@commands.is_owner()
async def sync(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=MY_GUILD)
    synced = await bot.tree.sync()
    print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands.")  
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands.", ephemeral=True)
        
async def loadCogs():
    for cog in cogs:
        try:
            await bot.load_extension(f"Cogs.{cog}")
            success.append(cog)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            failed.append(cog)

async def main():
    await loadCogs()

asyncio.run(main())

with open("views.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
    views_data = json.load(f)
    
views = views_data.get("views", [])

async def setup_hook():
    for info in views:
        view, persistentButtonMsgID = info.split("|")
        persistentButtonMsgID = int(persistentButtonMsgID)
        
        if view in globals():
            persistentView = globals()[view]
            instance = persistentView()
            
            bot.add_view(instance, message_id=persistentButtonMsgID)
            print(f"The '{view}' view has been refreshed")
        else:
            print(f"The '{view}' view was not found and has not been refreshed.")

    

bot.setup_hook = setup_hook

handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
bot.run(TOKEN, log_handler=handler)
```

Comment: We don't have enough information to answer your post. Does the bot ever go online? The `await self.bot.wait_until_ready()` makes it so that the task doesn't run until the bot is ready.

Comment: it goes online when i run python file "main.py", do you want me to add the code for that?

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful

Comment: @BlueRobin done